# Yii's urlManager and images

Tags: php, yii, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE with a plugin called 'responsive file manager' along with the Yii framework. I'm running into problems while displaying images because of the way Yii's url manager works.

Example:

```
http://mysite.local/images/image.png
```

gets treated as a controller / action and it gets a 404 error. Is there a workaround to exclude images / videos / etc from the urlManager in the main config file? I would prefer to avoid modifying the plugin to add Yii's CHtml image() function.

Any ideas?

**Update**
I noticed that yii's url manager only redirects to a controller/action if the images are stored in a child folder, ex.

```
http://mysite.local/media/images/image.png
```

instead of

```
http://mysite.local/media/image.png
```

However, I still need to have child folders because the file manager handles videos and images, I think it would be less confusing to the user if the structure kept them separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are having som problems in your htaccess file.

Does it include something like this?

```
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Yeah. Except the RewriteRule is the following: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1